# Eclipse icons below jmenubar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, icons, jmenubar

The tiny icons eclipse displays below its JMenuBar, what are those? How would one go about creating them? Are they part of the JMenuBar? Are they seperate from the JMenuBar?

Comment: Just to know in future, Eclipse uses SWT widget toolkit, not Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse but from some images I've seen it looks to me like they are buttons on a JToolBar.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: @Chris Gray and in most cases is required to change used Layout Manager for JToolBar